# Get django object id based on model attribute

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have a basic model named "Places" which has this view:

```
def view_index(request, place_name):
```

The user will access that view with a URL like this one:

```
http://server.com/kansas
```

"kansas" is a value stored in a field named "name" inside the model "Places".

The problem is that I can't figure out how to obtain the object id based just on the object name. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Like this:

```
place = Places.objects.get(name='kansas')
print(place.id)
```

Answer (score 18):

Since you only want `id`, you should only query for `id`.  A naive `get` will retrieve all fields on the database row.  Either of these methods will only retrieve the data you want.

```
id = Place.objects.filter(name='kansas').values('id')[0]['id']
```

Or with values_list:

```
id = Place.objects.filter(name='kansas').values_list('id', flat=True).first()
```

Another method uses `only`:

```
id = Place.objects.only('id').get(name='kansas').id
```

Comment: Will this perform more efficiently compared to the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, but whether the difference matters is a function of the rest of the columns.  If the table happens to have a giant text or json field with megs worth of data in it, then DEFINITELY!

Answer (score 5):

What does your URL mapping for that view look like?  Assuming you're capturing the part of your URL with `"kansas"` in it and that is getting set to the `place_name` argument, you'll have to do a simple `filter` on your model's manager on whatever model field you're looking for `"kansas"` in.

If your URL mapping looks like:

```
('(?P<place_name>\w+)$', 'myapp.view.view_index')
```

Then you should be able to do just

```
object_list = Model.objects.filter(place_name = place_name)
```

to get a list of objects who have a `place_name` that matches the one in the URL.  From there, each of the objects in that list should have an `id` (unless you've renamed the ID field) that you can get to like any other python object attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted responses, you can explore ids of all places in your 'Place' model as below:

Use list comprehension or any other convenient data structure.

```
objects = Place.objects.all()
id_name_pair = [(object.id, object.name) for object in objects]
```

This will give list of tuples with each name of your 'Place' model with it's corresponding id.