# Django content_type object_id

Tags: django, generic-foreign-key

I have model call Report:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='report_owner')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

How do I find out what the object_id of my models in all my apps are?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get django object id based on model attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659360/get-django-object-id-based-on-model-attribute)

Comment: I don't see how as my question deals with ContentType and not model fields.

Answer (score 3):

so I found the answer in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#methods-on-contenttype-instances).

```
 from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
my_model = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='myapp', model='mymodel')
```

Then

```
my_model.id
```

returns the object_id.