# Django nested objects, different serializers GET and POST

Tags: python, django, serialization, nested

this is a follow-up to this question I had [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563763/django-post-request-nested-object-primary-key).

I can now POST a new AP object using user Primary Key and after commenting this line in the AP serializer `user = UserIndexSerializer()`:

Postman request:

```
{
    "user":1,
    "name":"Max AP 05"
}
```

However the problem that I now have is that the initial UserIdexSerializer is rendered useless.

This serializer determines the fields to show in a GET request but in consequence imposes the fields required in a POST request.
What I'm trying to do is:

- POST a new AP object only using the user ID
- Show the UserIndexSerializer fields during a GET request (first_name,
  last_name, but not the ID)

How can I make this work?

I have found and read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22616973/django-rest-framework-use-different-serializers-in-the-same-modelviewset).

I tried using different views, one for listing my models and one for creating a new one:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models.model_art_piece import AP
from .serializers_user import *


class APIndexSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserIndexSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = AP
        fields = [
            'id',
            'user',
            'name'
        ]

class APCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserIDSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = AP
        fields = [
            'id',
            'user',
            'name'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ap = AP.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return ap

class APDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AP
        fields = '__all__'
```

And I also tried creating different serializers:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models.model_user import User


class UserIndexSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'first_name',
            'last_name'
        ]

class UserIDSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'id'
        ]

class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

This has not work at all, can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want is to get the nested object during get. I had the same problem which I resolved with this in my serializer.

```
class APIndexSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AP
        fields = ['id','user','name']

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        self.fields['user'] = UserIndexSerializer()
        return super(APIndexSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
```

You can with this create with id and get with nested information of user.

Comment: Just to understand better the return of the to_representation method. Is the obj passed in the to_representation(obj) the created object using the super() function, inheriting from the serializer and the current AP instance being processed?

Answer (score 2):

I will give you an example to explain how to use different serializers in GET/POST for relational fields.

There is a Ticket model and it has a foreign key refers to User model. In your POST to create a ticket, you wanna user's id to create the object. In your GET to get ticket's details, you wanna show the user's details rather than ids.

```
Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In your serializer file, you then have

```
class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')


class TicketPostSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = '__all__'


class TicketDetailSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserDetailSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = '__all__'
```

Then, in Ticket's view function, you then have:

```
class TicketViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TicketPostSerializer
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action in ['list', 'retrieve']:
            return TicketDetailSerializer
```

All set, you are free to go.

Comment: I see what you did @JunZhou, but when i try it, it gives me the error `'AP' object has no attribute 'action'`